# Rewriting automorphism of matrix algebra in terms of automorphisms of the underlying ring?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, reference-request, modules

I've used the following idea as a black box for some time now, but it occurred to me I don't fully understand why it's true.

Suppose $A=M_n(R)$ is the algebra of square matrices over some division ring $R$. Then for any $\phi\in\operatorname{Aut}(A)$, we can actually write $\phi$ as the composition of an automorphism induced by an automorphism $\psi$ of $R$ and the conjugation by some unit of $A$. 
More explicitly, for $\psi\in\operatorname{Aut}(R)$, this induces an automorphism $\tilde{\psi}$ of $A$ by applying $\psi$ to each of the entries in the matrix, for example,
$$
M=\begin{pmatrix}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\ a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{pmatrix}
\mapsto
\tilde{\psi}(M)\begin{pmatrix}
\psi(a_{11}) & \psi(a_{12})\\ \psi(a_{21}) & \psi(a_{22})
\end{pmatrix}
$$
and then we can conjugate by an invertible matrix in $A$, say $N$, to get $N\tilde{\psi}(M)N^{-1}$. I don't think the order of applying $\tilde{\psi}$ or conjugating matters, since if I conjugate first, then I could apply a different $\tilde{\psi}$. So the composition would be something like $\phi=\varphi_N\circ\tilde{\psi}$ where $\varphi_N$ is the conjugation by $N$ map.

My question is, why can any automorphism $\phi$ of $A$ actually be decomposed in this way?

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out what your second paragraph means... can you formalize it a bit more please :)

Comment: @Nastassja: It think it should say "conjugation by" instead of "conjugation of"? By the automorphism induced by some $\psi\in\operatorname{Aut}(R)$ I presume you mean the componentwise application of $\psi$?

Comment: @rschwieb Sorry, I admit I'm having a somewhat hard time expressing what I mean :(. I will try to fix it.

Comment: In your statement about your "gut feeling" you never use $\rho$. What did you intend to say?

Comment: @Nastassja: if $\rho$ is an automorphism of $A$ then it isn't an element of $A$, and I'm not sure what you mean by conjugation here. Perhaps you mean the following: giving $N$ an $A$-module structure means specifying a ring map $A \to \text{End}(N)$, and any _endomorphism_ $\rho : A \to A$ (no invertibility necessary) defines a new ring map $A \to A \to \text{End}(N)$ by composition.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Thanks, I think you've phrased it much better and more accurately than I did.

Comment: @Nastassja I'm curious: do you happen to remember what you were studying when you started using this "black box"? Or some problems you applied it in? I just wonder if it's something else in disguise.

Comment: @rschwieb This was from the later portions of a second course in linear algebra I took last fall. I've tried to formalize and better explain the second paragraph. It was too vague this first time around.

Answer (score 1):

A special case: Let $\phi:M_n(R)\to M_n(R)$ be an automorphism. It restricts to an automorphism of the center of $M_n(R)$, which is the same as the center $K=Z(R)$ of $R$, which is a field. If we suppose that this restriction $\phi|_K$ is the identity and that $R$ is finite, then the Nother-Skolem theorem tells us that $\phi$ is inner, that is, by conjugation by an invertible element of $M_n(R)$.

The general case is stated in *Algebra IX: Finite Groups of Lie Type, Finite-dimensional Division Algebras*, by A. I. Kostrikin and I. R. Shafarevich, in chapter II, section 3. They see $M_n(R)$ as an algebra over a field and look for automorphisms which are algebra automorphisms: but you can always take the ground field to be the prime field of the center of $R$.

Comment: Thanks Mariano. I found a copy of _Algebra IX_, and Chapter II, Section 3 is about the Brauer Complex. Are you referring to section 2 on Semisimple Conjugacy Classes of $G^F$? Sorry if I'm wrong, I don't understand much in this book.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're describing is basically the contents of the [Skolem-Noether theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skolem-Noether_theorem) which states that a central simple algebra $A$ with center $Z$ has the property that every $Z$-algebra automorphism is inner.

So in the case of a matrix ring over a field $\mathbb{F}$, all $F$-linear automorphisms are inner.

However if your automorphism may not be $R$-linear and it may not be central if you use a division ring $R$, that is, the map doesn't fix $R$. Here you could say: "Well, $\phi(R)$ is isomorphic to $R$, so why don't I just identify $R$ with $\phi(R)$ and pretend the original map is $R$ linear?"

This sounds a little bit like what you described, although it's beyond what I've seen stated with the Skolem-Noether theorem.

Comment: The quoted text is sleep-deprived speculation. While central simple algebras have only inner automorphisms, I doubt you can say the same for general ring automorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $D$ is a division ring, and
$\varphi$ is a ring automorphism of $M_n(D)$. As usual, identify
$D$ with the subring of scalar matrices in $M_n(D)$.
Note that every automorphism $\psi$ of $D$ extends to an automorphism
$\psi\colon(d_{ij})\mapsto(\psi(d_{ij}))$ of $M_n(D)$.
Then there exists a matrix $A\in M_n(D)$ and an automorphism
$\psi$ of $D$ such that
$\varphi(B)=A\psi(B)A^{-1}$ for every $B\in M_n(D)$.

Elementary linear algebra proof: Identify $M_n(D)=\rm{End}_D(V)$, where $V=D^n$ is the right $D$ vector space of
column vectors, and $M_n(D)$ acts by matrix multiplication from the left.
Let $\{e_i\}\subset V$ and $\{e_{ij}\}\subset M_n(D)$ denote the standard
bases, so that $e_{ij}e_k=\delta_{jk}e_i$ (Kronecker delta).
Fix $u\in V$ such that $v_1=\varphi(e_{11})u\neq 0$, and set
$v_i=\varphi(e_{i1})v_1$ for $2\leq i\leq n$.
Since $\varphi(e_{1i})v_i=v_1$, $v_i\neq 0$.
Then since $\varphi(e_{ii})v_i=v_i$ for all $i$ and
$\varphi(e_{jj})v_i=0$ for all $j\neq i$, $\{v_i\}$ is a basis for $V$.
Define $A\in M_n(D)$ by $Ae_i=v_i$. For every $i,j,k$ we have
$$
\varphi(e_{ij})Ae_k=\varphi(e_{ij})v_k=\varphi(e_{ij}e_{k1})v_1
=\delta_{jk}v_i=Ae_{ij}e_k,
$$
and hence $\varphi(e_{ij})A=Ae_{ij}$.
Conclude that $\varphi(e_{ij})=Ae_{ij}A^{-1}$ for all $i,j$.

Now suppose $d\in D\subset M_n(D)$.
Then $\varphi(d)\varphi(e_{ij})=\varphi(e_{ij})\varphi(d)$, and hence
$$(A^{-1}\varphi(d)A)e_{ij}=e_{ij}(A^{-1}\varphi(d)A)\quad
\text{for all}\ i,j.$$
Conclude that $A^{-1}\varphi(d)A\in D$ is a scalar matrix, and
hence that $\psi\colon d\mapsto A^{-1}\varphi(d)A$ is a well defined
automorphism of $D$.

We've verified that $\varphi(B)=A\psi(B)A^{-1}$ for $B=e_{ij}$ and
for $B\in D$. Since $(d_{ij})=\sum d_{ij}e_{ij}$
for every $(d_{ij})\in M_n(D)$, this establishes the claim.